# Nested form, update and creation in one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I wanted to set up a form where I can edit some nested objects and create new objects at the same time.

Thats what I got until now:

### Models:

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :org_unit

    validates_uniqueness_of :name
    validates_presence_of :name, :tablename, :rate_order_no, :ratevalue
end

class OrgUnit < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :rates
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :rates
end
```

### Controller:

```
class OrgUnitsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_org_unit, only: [:show, :edit]


def index
    @org_units = OrgUnit.all
end

def show
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @org_unit.update(org_unit_params)
        redirect_to @org_unit, notice: 'Update successfull.'
    else
        render action: 'edit'
    end
end

private

def set_org_unit
    @org_unit = OrgUnit.find(params[:id])
    @rates = @org_unit.rates
end

def org_unit_params
    params.require(:org_unit).permit(
        :rates_attributes => [:name, :tablename, :rate_order_no, :ratevalue]
    )
end
```

end

### Routes:

```
#Organisation Units
 get '/org_units/',             :to => 'org_units#index',   :as => 'org_units'
 get '/org_units/:id',          :to => 'org_units#show',    :as => 'org_unit'
 get '/org_units/:id/edit',     :to => 'org_units#edit',    :as => 'edit_org_unit'
 put '/org_units/:id',          :to => 'org_units#update'
 patch '/org_units/:id',        :to => 'org_units#update'
```

### View:

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @org_unit do |f| %>

            <table id="ratetable" class="display">
                <thead>
                    <tr>    <th>Rate Name</th>  <th>Table</th>  <th>Department</th> <th>Value</th>  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <%= f.simple_fields_for :rates, :wrapper => false do |ff| %>
                        <tr class="fields">
                            <td><%= ff.input :name, label: false, required: true %></td>
                            <td><%= ff.input :tablename, collection: ["Costs","Savings","CnQ"], label:false, required: true, prompt: "Select the table" %></td>
                            <td><%= ff.input :rate_order_no, collection: 1..19, label:false, required: true, prompt: "Select the row"%></td>
                            <td><%= ff.input :ratevalue, label: false, required: true %></td>
                        </tr>
                    <% end %>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a rate", :rates, :data => { :target => "#ratetable" }, :class => "btn btn-default" %></p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <%= f.submit "Save Rates", :class => "btn bnt-default" %>
<% end %>
```

Now if I click the submit button rails is taking every filled line and create a new rate with the attributes of org_unit_params. So the old rates are not updated and multiple times in my database then.

What I want is that he updates the old ones if they changed and create new records for the others.

It should have something to do with `create_or_update` but I cant put it together.

Would appreciate every hint.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: Okay, added the ':id' to 'permitted attributes' but its still not working. Anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I had to add :id to my permitted attributes:

```
def org_unit_params
    params.require(:org_unit).permit(:id, :name,
        rates_attributes: [:id, :name, :tablename, :rate_order_no, :ratevalue, :org_unit_id, :_destroy]
    )
end
```

But that wasnt enough :( So I had to add a hidden input field with :id in my fields_for and now it works:

```
                <%= f.simple_fields_for :rates, :wrapper => false do |ff| %>
                    <tr class="fields">
                        <td><%= ff.input :name, label: false %></td>
                        <td><%= ff.input :tablename, collection: ["Costs","Savings","CnQ"], label:false, prompt: "Select the table" %></td>
                        <td><%= ff.input :rate_order_no, collection: 1..19, label:false, prompt: "Select the row"%></td>
                        <td><%= ff.input :ratevalue, label: false, required: true %></td>
                        <td><%= ff.link_to_remove "Remove", :class => "btn btn-default" %></td>
                        <%= ff.input :id, :as => :hidden %>
                    </tr>
                <% end %>
```